# Что такое double brace инициализация?

Tags: java, brackets

Что означает синтаксис `{{ }}`(две двойных фигурных скобки) в Java?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Инициализация с помощью двойных скобок создает анонимный класс, производный от указанного класса, и обеспечивает блок инициализации внутри. Почти всегда используется для инициализации коллекций.

Пример:

```
new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
   add(1);
   add(2);
}};
```

`ArrayList` - "главный", внешний класс, первая скобка - скобка внешнего класса, вторая скобка - скобка блока инициализации. Пространство внутри скобок - блок инициализации.

Созданный класс имеет неявный указатель `this` на  внешний класс. Хотя обычно это не проблема, в некоторых случаях это может быть плохо(из-за создания классов), например, при сериализации или сборке мусора, и об этом стоит знать.

Java 9 ввел удобные методы `List.of`, `Set.of` и `Map.of`, которые следует использовать. Они быстрее и эффективнее, чем инициализатор с двойными скобками.

---

### Проблемы при использовании такой конструкции:

**1. Вы создаете слишком много анонимных классов**

Каждый раз, когда вы используете двойную инициализацию, создается новый класс.

Пример

```
Map source = new HashMap(){{
    put("firstName", "John");
    put("lastName", "Smith");
    put("organizations", new HashMap(){{
        put("0", new HashMap(){{
            put("id", "1234");
        }});
        put("abc", new HashMap(){{
            put("id", "5678");
        }});
    }});
}};
```

будет создавать эти классы:

```
Test$1$1$1.class
Test$1$1$2.class
Test$1$1.class
Test$1.class
Test.class
```

Конечно, это не так много, но если вы используете эту конструкцию 10-100-1000 раз, то вы используете кучу памяти всего лишь ради синтаксического сахара.

**2. Вы потенциально создаете утечку памяти!** 
Если вы примените следующий код, например в методе, то вызывающие метод могут не подозревать о слишком больших ресурсах, которые невозможно собрать GC.

[Больше о производительности при использовании двойных скобок(enSO).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization)

---

Еще 1 пример инициализации с помощью двойных скобок:

```
private static class IndustrialRaverMonkey
  extends Creature.Base {{
    life = 46;
    strength = 35;
    charisma = 91;
    weapon = 2;
  }}

private static class DwarvenAngel
  extends Creature.Base {{
    life = 540;
    strength = 6;
    charisma = 144;
    weapon = 50;
  }}
```

Comment: Что за бред! `вторая скобка - скобка анонимного класса` - это просто блок инициализации! Какой анонимный класс? %)%)%)%)

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець ааа, ну да. Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: П.2 в оригинальном ответе плохо описан, непонятно что там создает утечку, но в оригинальном ответе есть пример кода который именованием полей подсказывает в чем утечка.  В этот пункт лучше включить перевод из ответа https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054360/do-anonymous-classes-always-maintain-a-reference-to-their-enclosing-instance/20647717

Answer (score 1):

Внутренние фигурные скобки эквивалентны описанию конструктора без параметров:

```
class Clazz {{System.out.println("hello");}}
```

это то же самое что

```
class Clazz {
     Clazz(){
        System.out.println("hello");
     }
}
```

Comment: Есть разница в том, что блок инициализации выполняется всегда при создании экземпляра, а конструктор может быть не вызван, если есть, например, второй конструктор.